How to get a copy of a refusal letter for a Canadian visa application?
I applied for a tourist visa from Canada in July 2021, and my two daughters were my dependents. I had a refusal in January 2023, but somehow I have lost the refusal letter for my daughters. How can I get a copy of their refusal letters? My GCKey is also revoked.

I'm not familiar with Canada's data protection laws, but you should be able to get a copy of your records from the Canadian immigration authority. Assuming your daughters are under the age of 16/18, you should be able to get a copy of theirs as well.
The general procedure to get a copy of your records from Canadian governmental agencies is detail here. https://www.priv.gc.ca/en/privacy-topics/accessing-personal-information/api_gov/#fedgov
